# Msbuild from command line does not copy files that don't need compiling to the output directory

Tags: msbuild

In my project (an XNA .contentproj) I have files that need compiling, and files that just need to be copied to the output directory:

```
    <Compile Include="Foo.cs" />
    <None Include="Bar.xml">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
```

This works fine when i'm compiling from visual studio, but when I build the project from the **command line**, these 'None' files are not copied to the output directory. I tried setting the copy to 'Always' as well.

How can I tell msbuild it should do that?

EDIT: I found out this is only for XNA .contenproj msbuild files. Maybe I'm missing some msbuild parameters.

EDIT2: I have now worked around this by just manually copying all non-build content to the output directory. Which works fine, but it still feels 'wrong'.

Comment: To debug the difference between VS and command-line, you could do "tools\option\projects&solutions\build&run" and set verbosity to diagnostic, and compare with `/v:diag` on the command-line (diff the two), presumably VS is setting some property that you could also set on command-line with `/p:name=val`.

Answer (score 1):

Just make it e.g.

```
<None Include="Bar.xml">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

(if you change the properties inside VS, it should do that).

Comment: Hmm ok, i have the CopyTuOutputDirectory set as PreserveNewest, which doesn't work. I'll try setting to 'Always'.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either. Sorry, I should have specified this in my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because of the specific targets definition for XNA projects (either in general, or your specific one).
"None" items are not special in any way, they are treated just like any other item, in the sense that unless there's a specific task that actually handles them, they won't have any effect. The common targets files - e.g. Microsoft.CSharp.targets; Microsoft.Cpp.targets - do handle 'None' items in the proper way as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629388.aspx).

One possibility, is that there is a target already defined that copies the None items in your project file, but that this target is not included in the DefaultTargets attribute of the 'Project' node of your project file. If that's the case, you can still get that target invoked by passing it in the [/target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) command-line argument.

The other (and less likely) option is that VS is properly handling these items even though there's no proper target defined in your project. There are several ways to work around this:

1. The straight forward way - define a target that copies the files and add it to the default targets, or alternatively put it in the targets chain with BeforeTargets/AfterTargets. For example (see documentation of the 'Copy' task [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx)):

> ```
>   <Target Name="CopyNoneItems">
>     <Copy SourceFiles="@(None)"
>     DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
>   </Target>
> ```

2. The hacky way - include a targets file that properly handles the 'none' items in your project file (e.g. Microsoft.CSharp.targets) - this is hacky because you're importing a bunch of other things that you don't need in the process, which may introduce other issues
3. The long way - Parse the targets files for CSharp (or any of the other project types that properly handles 'None' items) to see which internal imported targets file handles the 'None' items, and possibly import only that file. I have opted for #1 when I had the issue, so I'm not sure if there is such a clean .targets file that will actually work, since there are probably some dependencies between all these targets files

If you need to pick one of these, my recommendation would be to go with #1. It's easy and straight forward, and has the least side effects.